# How can I change the ownership of a Mail Merge in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I currently have a series of Mail Merges that I uploaded to our CRM 2011 system, but when attempting to use them under a different user I realized the ownership was assigned to the individual who created it and therefore not available to me.

I have tried opening the Mail Merge template to change the ownership level from 'Individual' to 'Organization', but the field is grayed out and read only. When creating a new template, that same field is set it 'Individual', grayed out, and read only. I have also checked the security role settings for the user, and they have full permissions for a Mail Merge template entity.

How do I change the ownership of a Mail Merge to 'Organization' so I can have all the the users of a system have access to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Mail Merge Document.
Select [Actions]
Make Available to Organization

[image: Mail Merge Assigning]

You Can also change the Owner through Using the [Assign…] ~Assuming you have either the permission to assign, or are the owner.